# Using only one dataprovider , how to pass data to many test methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, testng, junit4

Im using DataProvider in TestNG for my Selenium Scripts . My requirement is to just use a single DataProvider and pass the data to many test methods .

For example : Say i have 10 test methods , So i need to create a Single DataProvider , so that it can pass data to all those 10 Test methods.

Is it possible to do it ? If yes , how to implement it .

Or is there any alternative for this ??

Pl Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of your test method has **@Test** annotation, then you can simply add parameter to this as -

```
@Test(dataProvider="Name of your DataProvider")
```

You can do this with all of the 10 test methods & this will make them get data from your single DataProvider.

I hope it helps. . .cheers!!

Comment: But my 10 tests need to be passed with 10 different data values , Using a single DataProvider

Comment: check my answer that should help. your data provider needs to know which method to provide data for .

Comment: @jeevans please let me know if the **10 different data values** are present in same data source/excel ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

So your data provider needs to know for which method or class it is providing the data. I made the following implementation. So you can get the context of the calling method in a data provider and you can ask it what is the parent class name for which the data has to be provided, and then depending on that you can have multiple files which you can read and supply the data or have different rows in the same csv differentiated by class name from where you can read the required row

```
@DataProvider(name="getDataFromFile")
public static Iterator<Object[]> getDataFromFile(Method testMethod) throws Exception
{
    String expected=null;
    String className=testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
    Reporter.log("Providing data for class " + className,true);
    List<Map<String, String>> setupData = getTestDataFromCsv(classname);
  //provide data here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update on this:
I was looking for a solution for the same. But it is not possible to split the data provider. But no harm in reusing the data provider for all methods, the disadvantage is each method must use the complete list of arguments. All other options are more complex to implement and maintain. For my scenario, it is better than creating and maintaining separate data providers for each test methods.

```html
 @BeforeMethod
 public void setUp() {
  
  init(); 
  login= new LoginPage(myD);
  clientsearch = new ClientSearchPage(myD);
  toppanel= new TopPanelPage(myD);
 } 
 @Test(dataProvider="search_data")
 public void verifySearchByClientNumber(String clientnumber, String policynumber, String policynumberClient, String webreference,
   String webreferenceClient, String surname, String surnameClient, String forename, String forenameClient, String dob, String dobClient){ 
   
  login.Login(); 
  log.info("Logged in successfully, now in ClientSearch Page..");   
  log.info("Entering client number.." );
  clientsearch.enterClientNumber(clientnumber);
  log.info("Clicking on the Search button ..." );
  clientsearch.clickSearchButton();  
  log.info("Verifying Client present in results.." );
  boolean res=clientsearch.isClientPresent(clientnumber);
  Assert.assertEquals(res, true,"Assertion failed !!");
  toppanel.clickLogoutButton();
 }  

 @Test(dataProvider="search_data")
 public void verifySearchByPolicyNumber(String clientnumber, String policynumber, String policynumberClient, String webreference,
   String webreferenceClient, String surname, String surnameClient, String forename, String forenameClient, String dob, String dobClient){
    
  login.Login(); 
  log.info("Logged in successfully, now in ClientSearch Page..");   
  log.info("Entering Policy number.." );
  clientsearch.enterPolicyNumber(policynumber);
  log.info("Clicking on the Search button ..." );
  clientsearch.clickSearchButton(); 
  log.info("Verifying Client present in results.." );
  boolean res=clientsearch.isClientPresent(policynumberClient);
  Assert.assertEquals(res, true,"Assertion failed !!");
  toppanel.clickLogoutButton();
 } 

 //More methods here with same data provider....
 
 @AfterMethod
 public void endTest() {
  
  myD.quit();
 }
```